# Scrape Instagram Hashtag page with BeautifulSoup and python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I followed the BeautifulSoup tutorial to scrape informations from a website, I need to get links for instagram posts from the hashtag research page but I don't have any results,

```
url_tag = 'https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/food'
response_url_tag = get(url_tag)

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response_url_tag.text, 'html.parser')
#print(html_soup.prettify())

for link in html_soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

[image: HTML DOM]
How can I scrape all the links? What do I need to change in my code ?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to this with BeautifulSoup. The reason is that, as in many modern web apps, the links you are able to see in your browser's inspector are not in the html code, but rendered with javascript inside the browser.
If you `curl` the URL, you will not get any `<a>` tags in the downloaded HTML.

A solution with instagram is to query Graphql. With your example, it would be with this URL : `https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/food/?__a=1`

The parameter in the URL tells Instagram to produce [Graphql](https://graphql.org) instead of HTML. Then you'd have to parse this with python. The [Graphene library](https://graphene-python.org) does this.

Or you can use for example [Instagram Scraper](https://github.com/rarcega/instagram-scraper) which wraps this all for you.